# lxml, get xml between elements

Tags: python, xml, xpath

given this sample xml:

```
<xml>
<pb facs="id1" />
  <aa></aa>
  <aa></aa>
  <lot-of-xml></lot-of-xml>
<pb facs="id2" />
  <bb></bb>
  <bb></bb>
  <lot-of-xml></lot-of-xml>
</xml>
```

i need to parse it and get **all** the content between `pb`, saving into distinct external files.

expected result:

```
$ cat id1
  <aa></aa>
  <aa></aa>
  <lot-of-xml></lot-of-xml>

$ cat id2
  <bb></bb>
  <bb></bb>
  <lot-of-xml></lot-of-xml>
```

what is the correct xpath axe to use?

```
from lxml import etree
xml = etree.parse("sample.xml")

for pb in xml.xpath('//pb'):
    filename = pb.xpath('@facs')[0]
    f = open(filename, 'w')

    content =  **{{ HOW TO GET THE CONTENT HERE? }}**

    f.write(content)
    f.close()
```

is there any xpath expression to get all descendants and stop when reached a new `pb`?

Comment: i was thinking something like: `followings = pb.xpath("./following-sibling::*[not(self::pb)]")` but doesn't work. how to get all **following-sibling** and stop when reached the next **pb**?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I tested this code:

```
lists = []
for node in tree.findall('*'):
    if node.tag == 'pb':
        lists.append([])
    else:
        lists[-1].append(node)
```

Output:

```
>>> lists
[[<Element test at 2967fa8>, <Element test at 2a89030>, <Element lot-of-xml at 2a89080>], [<Element test at 2a89170>, <Element test at 2a891c0>, <Element lot-of-xml at 2a89210>]]
```

Input file (just in case):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xml>
<pb facs="id1" />
  <test></test>
  <test></test>
  <lot-of-xml></lot-of-xml>
<pb facs="id2" />
  <test></test>
  <test></test>
  <lot-of-xml></lot-of-xml>
</xml>
```

Comment: sorry, i edited my question. the xml between **pb** is very variable, and contains many differents elements.

Comment: OK, `pb.findall('*')` will iterate all of them.

Comment: `pb.findall()` will stops at the next **pb**?

Comment: You're right, Robert. I missed that <pb/> is self-closed. Updated answer.

Comment: edited again the question. hope is more clear now. i need to deal separately with the xml contained between pb

Comment: Do you need removing all <pb/> tags? Just create new `ElementTree` object and add `Element` instances from initial tree into new one. Or create new tree for each `list in lists`, for example, and then call method `write()` for tree.

Comment: Function `ElementTree.tostring(element)` is also useful.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to extract the tag between two pb's? If yes then that's not quite possible because it is not a tag in between pb's rather than an individual tag on the same level as pb as you have closed the tag pb . If you close the tag after the test tag then test can become a child of pb.

In other words if your xml is like this:

```
<xml>
<pb facs="id1">
  <test></test>
</pb>
  <test></test>
<pb facs="id2" />
  <test></test>
  <test></test>
</xml>
```

Then you can use

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
    for subchild in child:
        print subchild
```

to print the subchild('test') with pb as a parent.
Well if that's not the case (you just want to extract the attributes of pb tag)then you can use either of the two methods shown below to extract the elements.
With python's inbuilt [etree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
   if child.get('facs'):
       print child.get('facs')
```

With the lxml library you can parse it like this:

```
tree = etree.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
    if child.get('facs'):
        print child.get('facs')
```